# How to restrict Child Class from accessing super Class methods?

Tags: java, class, oop

**For Example :**

I Have Class

```
package test.inheritance.checkMultiple;

public class Company {



protected void run (){
    System.out.println("Time to Run");
}

}

public class Department extends Company {



    public void testDepartment()
    {
        Department d =new Department();
        d.run();
    }

}


public class Employee extends Department{


    public void checkValidEmployee(){
        Employee e =new Employee();
        e.run();
        e.testDepartment();

    }

    public static void main (String[] artgs)
    {
        Employee e =new Employee();
        e.checkValidEmployee();
        System.out.println("Valid Emplyee");
    }

}
```

1) I don't want employee class to have access to run method. What should I do for this?

2) If I wanted to give employee class the access to run method, but not department class, what should I do?

Comment: Maybe you should use composition instead of inheritance ?

Comment: A Company _contains_ Departments, and Departments _contain_ Employees.  They do not form an inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: What exactly do you want your Employee class to do? Do you mean that you don't want checkValidEmployees to be able call run?

Comment: Yes Thats what i want.

Comment: I dont want checkValidEmployee()  to call run method

Comment: @ViploveGujrathi in a properly designed class hierarchy this would be a non-issue because an `Employee` _is not a_ `Department` and would never inherit the `Department` class's methods.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't, as every childclass has to be a valid class of which it is a child - see [Liskovs substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

So **use composition instead of inheritance** as suggested by @Michael Laffargue.

I don't know what exactly you want to achieve, but it should look somewhat more like the following, with Company being a member variable of Department which in turn is a member variable of an Employee.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Company
{
    private final String name;

    public Company(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("Time to Run");
    }
}

public class Department
{
    private static final List<String> VALID_DEPARTMENTS = Arrays.asList("IT");
    private final String name;
    private final Company company;

    public Department(String name, Company company)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.company = company;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }

    public Company getCompany()
    {
        return this.company;
    }

    public void checkValid()
    {
        if (!VALID_DEPARTMENTS.contains(this.name))
            throw new AssertionError();
    }

}

public class Employee
{
    private final Department department;
    private final String name;

    public Employee(String name, Department department)
    {
        this.department = department;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void checkValid()
    {
        this.department.getCompany().run();
        this.department.checkValid();
    }

    public Department getDepartment()
    {
        return this.department;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }
}

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] artgs)
    {
        final Company company = new Company("Company");
        final Department department = new Department("IT", company);
        Employee e = new Employee("Peter", department);
        e.checkValid();
        System.out.println("Valid Emplyee");
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for correct design principles, and not just parroting the trivial answer to the incorrectly stated question.

Comment: @flob can please help me how to achieve the same using composition

Comment: If I would know what you are up to, what your use case is?

Comment: @flob Departments can change name and Employees can change name (e.g. marriage) and Department.  Those fields shouldn't be `final`  (just sayin')

Comment: Just use it as an example what the difference between composition and inheritance would be. Everything else is up to you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just declare the methods which you don't want to be accessed by child class as `private`.When you use the `private` access specifier for some method then that particular method is not inherited by the child class.You can see the following table to know that how access specifiers work

[image]

also study this link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Comment: I have already done that    I have put Company and Department in one Package while employee in another

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the method private and the children class shall not be able to see it.

Also you can use the default modifier (package) and place the children in a different package.

Comment: I upvoted you because you had a downvote although this is the answer to the question :)

Comment: @Rafael I have already done that    I have put Company and Department in one Package while employee in another

Comment: Yes but you shall remove the 'public' in order to use the default scope.

Comment: @Rafael I tried doing both turned class to default scope and method to protected but it doesn't work i can still access the run method

Comment: I mean method modifier not class modifier. Method to protected will not works since "protected" purpose is that child classes could access parent methods even from another package.